# Android Studio Google Map V2 fragment rendering

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-studio

I tried to write a test demo for Google Map V2 in Android Studio. I followed every step from [Androidhive Google Map V2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) or better I think I need.

I'm using the same layout_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but I'm getting always the same rendering problem:

> Rendering Problems
>   A `<fragment>` tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout...

I have absolutely no idea what's the problem. Did I forget something?
I just need to add Google services in the build.gradle like

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
```

I copied the manifest from the demo and changed the API Key.

Comment: this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307527/4833705. In short, just add this line of code to your fragment `tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_gallery_item`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Rendering Problems
>   A tag `<fragment>` allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout...

This is just the preview window telling you that it can't display a preview for the `<Fragment.../>` tag, because it doesn't know what kind of fragment you're going to put in it.  You can safely ignore that message - your actual app will render the fragment fine when you run it (as long as you code it up correctly!).

Answer (score 76):

The accepted answer is not wrong but it does not help.

As Dan wrote, Android Studio (also Version 1.0) will not display the map.
Maps needs an API key and dynamic processed code, maybe some day we will have that but so far not.
I've a 5 minute solution for those who want to see their app properly in layout preview:
[image]

To properly develop I still needed something else than a blank background.
I added overlays and buttons on top of the map, I really needed to see the map while placing elements over it.
The solution is simple:
 1. Make a screenshot of your app with the map running (Power + Volume Down)
 2. Download the screenshot and use an image editor to remove the top and bottom UI elements, so you will end up with only the map itself as an image.
 3. Import that image into android studio drawables
 4. create a new layout, name it `dummy_mapviewfragment`, put only a linearlayout and an imageview in
 5. make the imageview "fill" the parent, and set "src" to the cropped image you just imported
 6. back to your layout, add this into your Mapview Fragment xml :

```
 tools:layout="@layout/dummy_mapviewfragment"/>
```

That's it, now you will have a non-interactive mapview fragment which displays a real map.
Your app will look like it looks on your mobile phone.
If you made errors in your image cropping you can "fix" it by setting the image scale to "centerCrop" so it will properly stretch out.

*Update: You can get a screenshot without need to crop directly from within Androidstudio! Makes it a bit more convenient ;)*

Comment: I commend you, sir! I came here to understand the rendering error message, however, I'm really impressed with your ingenuity, and I don't even need you solution (yet). I thank you!

Comment: @John after doing it, you are adding the buttons to the dummy_mapviewfragment? while trying to add them to the mapview i still get the x cross with the mouse that i cant add them

Comment: I am using a relativelayout for the design, the fragment is just one child of the layout.  
The button is another child. 
You can ad anything there and position it the way you want. It will appear exactly the same on your phone.

Comment: This is out of the box thinking.

Comment: The new version of Android Studio (2.1) will suggest layouts for you (and it's often right).  But sometimes it uses `layout="@layout\some_layout"`, sometimes `tools:layout="@layout\some_layout"`, and sometimes both.  Do you understand the difference?  I'm still trying to catch up on all the new material design xml tags.

Comment: Maps aside, this answer also works if you want to preview any arbitrary `Fragment` layout without running your app in the emulator.

Comment: You don't need the `LinearLayout`, just put `ImageView` as the root in `dummy_mapviewfragment`. I'd also name it `preview_map_fragment`. Also, I don't get your comment about not needing to crop from Android Studio. I used it to take the screenshot, but had to crop it nevertheless.

Comment: BTW How do you make sure the layout and the image are not included in the final APK that you build?

Answer (score 4):

Add a dummy layout "@android:layout/simple_gallery_item" as:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="317dp"
    android:layout_height="385dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.XYZ.googlemaps.MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/simple_gallery_item"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio automatically offers a solution within the error description, which is adding the name of the fragment layout.

> tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my"