# Android Studio Rendering fragment issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am, at the moment, trying to make a google maps app using android studio.

Right now, everything is fine, except for one thing, when i go to the "Design" Tab, in the XML file i have this Redering message:

> Rendering Problems A tag  allows a layout file to
>   dynamically include different layouts at runtime. At layout editing
>   time the specific layout to be used is not known. You can choose which
>   layout you would like previewed while editing the layout...

And the main problem is that I cannot use any of the gui components in my layout, I searched about my problem and i understood that with this error, people couldn't see their map but they could put on textfields, widgets, layouts, etc.
But for me, my preview is completly frozen and i can't do any modification.

[Picture of my android studio page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V08di.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

As you can change the fragments dynamically with your code, android studio doesn't know which layout to show in design time. This is the reason of your error.
To specifically tell android which layout to show, add `tools:layout="@layout/Your_layout_name"` attribute to your fragment.
There is also a shortcut link below the error description which you have told. Just click on the link and android will add it for you and you will see the fragment in your layout with no rendering error messages.
For a detailed example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.insane.fragmenttest.MainActivity">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/testFragmentID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.example.insane.fragmenttest.WorkOutDetails"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_work_out_details" /> <!-- This is the line you want to add. -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If the question is correct, please consider making it the accepted answer.

Comment: Useful, add tools:layout to xml and render is work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Designtime Layout Attributes. http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes

These attributes guide Android Studio on how to render run-time attributes in the layout editor.

I think you should include `tools:showIn="@layout/activity_maps"` in your the `<fragment>` part of your `google_maps_api.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this design for the fragment. This solved my problem. Also, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898992/android-studio-google-map-v2-fragment-rendering) link

```
<fragment
     android:id = "@+id/ma"
     android:name = "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     android:layout_width = "match_parent"
     android:layout_height = "match_parent"
     tools:context = "com.example.demomaps.MapsActivity"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I solved this easily..Simply ignore the message and click line that is showing below of the rendering messages. 
Actually fragment contains layout inner and if its not include its showing warning that it must contains you can simply ignore this message below the warning then this rendering issue will be resolved.