# Android Studio preview rendering issue layout

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

I hope someone can help me with my Android Studio preview. I can't get the normal cell phone preview, but instead I get a rendering problem. I am not sure how to fix this and can't find any good solutions that seem to work.

Which layout should I pick? I have provided a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: link is dead... describe your problem exactly

Comment: it is not an error, run the app and you will see the map!

Comment: select  lower version from XML editor

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I the map works on my device. Just wondering how to get the normal preview in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a warning from Google maps fragment, you can ignore it clicking 'Do not warn about...'

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899667/6437300

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had seen that post but was wondering if there was a better solution to display the cell phone preview.