# Map fragment rendering errors

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I'm trying to build a map activity with the following XML:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.getfamiliarwiththemap.MapsActivity" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mLlayoutBottomButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button

    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select"
    android:textColor="#ffec00"
    android:background="#b600ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"

    />

    </LinearLayout>

</fragment>

    </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

And i keep getting the rendering error : Unknown fragment
Can someone teach me the correct way of installing this google play services SDK MANUALLY? i have a folder named google_play_services and that's all i want to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Google Map V2 fragment rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898992/android-studio-google-map-v2-fragment-rendering)

Comment: And can u tell me which answer should i consider? :| @Jace J McPherson All u guys know is how to bust duplicates ...

Comment: It seems like you should be able to read through the answers on that post and figure out what you want to do. You cannot render this fragment without creating your own custom layout. I won't leave an answer on a question which has already been answered elsewhere. Providing the link was the most helpful thing I could do.

Comment: It seems like i'm not of average intelligence , thank you anyway. @Jace J McPherson

Answer (score -2):

try using `class` instead of `android:name`:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.getfamiliarwiththemap.MapsActivity" >
```

Comment: I tried this and i got :No resource identifier found for attribute 'class' in package 'android'

Comment: have you added GoogleMap dependency?